# Как конвертировать jade/pug в webpack?

Tags: webpack, jade, pug

Недавно перешел с Gulp'а на WebPack, и понял что не могу элементарно настроить конвертацию из jade в html, как я понял, webpack работает совсем не так как Gulp. В Gulp я просто писал свои таски для конвертации jade'а в html и у меня на выходе появлялись html страницы. Объясните пожалуйста, как сделать что-то подобное в webpack, и если так не делают, то как тогда работают с jade'ом в Webpack'е?

P.S. Хороший пример бы не помешал

Comment: Я знаю ответ но давать его не буду, т.к. он правильный на 90%. Остальные 10% можно выразить словами - "мир сошел с ума". Почему? Потому что в погоне за славой новички кидаются на все что напоминает кость. Так же и с jade. Создатели плагинов для webpack сами наверное никогда не работали с этим препроцессором и решили "чё там, ченить сделаем" и сделали компиляцию только в строку, для того чтобы использовать в браузе. Они, "уткины дети" даже название придумали "изоморфый pug" :) В общем ответ - не ставьте pug ставьте старый jade-htm-loader, он хоть как-то ещё компилирует в html. С одним НО...

Comment: ... НО! он не обнавляет себя после компиляции, чувствуешь себя как чмо после десятка перезапуска. Надеюсь кто-нибудь найдет ответ и окажется что я просто не совсем додумался до решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает следующий пример:

```
npm i pug-loader -D
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
loaders: [
     // pug
     {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            loader: "pug-loader"
     }
]
```

*Подключаем шаблон*

```
var template = require('./views/layout.pug');
```

Если указывать loader в вызове (Например: require("pug!./file.pug")) могут возникнуть проблемы при использовании миксинов в pug.

Answer (score 0):

Особенность webpack - в том, что на выходе его всегда будет js-пакет. Таким образом, вы можете превратить jade в html только в том случае, когда он используется в каком-нибудь js-файле.

Чтобы загрузить jade/pug в webpack - вам надо использовать [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader):

```
var template = require("pug!./file.pug");
```

Не забудьте установить пакет pug-loader через npm.

Чтобы получить шаблон в отдельном файле - можете попробовать воспользоваться загрузчиком file:

```
var link = require("file!pug!./file.pug");
```

Если строка выше не сработает - можно попробовать добавить extract:

```
var link = require("file!extract!pug!./file.pug");
```

Comment: jade-html-loader компилирует в файлы, это как бы стандарт. То что другие не могут, это проблема вызвана мифическими существами из гарри поттера, которые проникают в мозг через уши.